# Как правильно: "Сократить расходы на перевозке" или "сократить расходы на перевозку"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать : "сократить расходы на перевозке грузов" или "сократить расходы на перевозку грузов"? Какое грамматическое обоснование?
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

"На перевозке" можно сэкономить (сэкономить на чём? - на перевозке). Сократить( на что?) на перевозку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но здесь просьба рассмотреть именно с использованием словосочетания "сократить расходы на", а не "сэкономить".  Затруднение в корректном применении падежа слова, следующего за данным  словосочетанием. Винительный или предложный?

Comment: Но ведь Вам ясно ответили: сократить расходы НА ЧТО?На перевозку - вин.п. Это управление глагола сократить и сочетаемость сущ. расходы (на что? какие?)

Comment: Людмила, с винительным падежом все вполне ясно. Дело в том, что я пытаюсь доказать, что в данном контексте употребление предложного является ошибкой и возможна только форма "сократить расходы на + существительное в вин.п."  Я не права?

Comment: Да, это так, сократить на чём? - неверное управление, только сократить на что?

Answer (score 1):

Наталья,

Существуют специальные словари, в которых разъясняется, какие падежи в каких случаях следует употреблять. Это "словари управления". В одном из таких словарей (Д.Э. Розенталя) подробно перечислено, в каких случаях с предлогом **на** нужно использовать винительный / предложный падеж. Там, в частности, сказано следующее.

> **На с винительным падежом**   ...
>   11. При обозначении цели, к которой направлено действие, на целевое назначение предмета: *Дать на проверку; Отрез на костюм; Разрешение на
>   проезд; Стали упрашивать Феону Ивановну отдать младенца на воспитание*
>   (Ф.).

Это Ваш случай: **расходы на перевозку**.

Answer (score 0):

Эти варианты имеют разный смысл.

В первом случае выражение не совсем ясное, но речь может идти о сокращении *общих* расходов *за счет* того, что грузы "перевозятся" (каким-то дешёвым способом) а не напр. "переносятся".

В втором случае речь может идти об экономии, получаемой в процессе перевозки (выбор дешёвого способа, короткого пути и т. п.). Вместо "расходы на перевозку" здесь возможен альтернативный вариант "расходы по перевозке".

Answer (score 0):

Из двух предложенных вариантов верным считаю только один: "сократить расходы на перевозку грузов". Смысл таков: сделать перевозку грузов более дешевой.

Корректное управление: расходы (на что?) на перевозку (см. словари управления). Продполагаемые варианты управления "расходы (на чем?) на перевозке" и "сократить (на чем?) на перевозке" не являются корректным. Сравните: "сэкономить (на чем?) на перевозке" — управление корректное.
Допустимо также: расходы (какие?, по чему?) по перевозке.

Если вы хотите сократить общие расходы за счет удешевления или отмены перевозки, то возможен такой вариант: "сократить расходы за счет перевозки грузов".